# How can I calculate probablity of prediction in random forest classifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am writing program for calculating prediction using randomforest classifier algorithm of machine learning in python, and I am getting prediction in values.

I want prediction percentage or prediction probablity in percentage.

Can you help me on it?

Comment: Have you checked [the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba)?

Comment: yeah, I have already checked it but it gives multiple values using predict_prob

Comment: Yes. It is the probability of each of your classes. Pick the one you need

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `predict_proba()`. It will return an array contains the class probabilities of your model.

For more infomation, check [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba)

Comment: yeah , I have already used it but it gives multiple output values , I want prediction  of single output values in percentage

Comment: @mayur just slice the returned array for single class percentage.